# Why is my systemd "Requires=" statement being ignored?

Tags: linux, systemd

Despite having a `Requires=` on a mount unit (run-netns-vpn.mount) systemd will start my service before the unit is active!?

```
[Unit]
Description=Sets up networking in VPN namespace
Requires=run-netns-vpn.mount
After=run-netns-vpn.mount

[Service]
Type=oneshot
WorkingDirectory=/usr/namespaces
ExecStart=/usr/namespaces/vpn-network-setup.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is the status of the service depending on `run-netns-vpn.mount`:

```
vpn-ns-setup.service - Sets up networking in VPN namespace
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vpn-ns-setup.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-10-07 16:36:34 BST; 2min 46s ago
  Process: 762 ExecStart=/usr/namespaces/vpn-network-setup.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 762 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 07 16:36:34 mediabox vpn-network-setup.sh[762]: + ip netns exec vpn ip rule add from 10.200.1.2 table 200
Oct 07 16:36:34 mediabox vpn-network-setup.sh[762]: Cannot open network namespace "vpn": No such file or directory
Oct 07 16:36:34 mediabox systemd[1]: vpn-ns-setup.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 07 16:36:34 mediabox systemd[1]: vpn-ns-setup.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 07 16:36:34 mediabox systemd[1]: Failed to start Sets up networking in VPN namespace.
```

This is the status of `run-netns-vpn.mount`

```
● run-netns-vpn.mount - /run/netns/vpn
   Loaded: loaded
   Active: active (mounted) since Sun 2018-10-07 16:36:47 BST; 3min 52s ago
    Where: /run/netns/vpn
     What: nsfs
```

The service was started at `16:36:34` while the mount was loaded at `16:36:47`. I would expect a) the service to wait for the mount b) to fail if it can't start.

For reference:

```
Linux mediabox 4.15.0-36-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 16:19:09 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl cat run-netns-vpn.mount`? Just mounting the `nsfs` filesystem to track network namespaces is not necessarily the same thing as actually *creating* the network namespace name "vpn": at least on Debian 9, the command `ip netns add vpn` will both create the namespace *and* mount the `nsfs` filesystem at the same time, so it's possible you don't need a dedicated mount unit for that. Just make sure `/run/netns` exists before running `ip netns add`!

Comment: The output is `No files found for run-netns-vpn.mount`. I didn't create a mount file manually. The mount appears when the nfs is created using `ip netns add vpn` as part of a custom `openvpn` service (using `--up`). Unfortunately that service shows up as running a few seconds before actually making the tunnel and executing other scripts, so using `Requires=` on that doesn't work.